# Getting Question marks for German characters in HTML using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have done quite a bit of searching and still can't seem to figure this out, so I apologize if there's a perfectly good answer out there.

I'm using PHP to access German words in MySQL and the unique characters (öäüß) show up as �.

I've tried

- Setting the Character set of the table to UTF8 with:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE Words CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
  ```
- Setting the communication link between PHP and MySQL to UTF8 (probably not correct terminology) after making the connection with:

  ```
  mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
  ```

  (as well as similar things like:

  ```
  mysql_query("set character_set_client='utf8'");
  mysql_query("set character_set_results='utf8'");
  mysql_query("set collation_connection='utf8_unicode_ci'");
  mysql_set_charset('utf8', $conn);
  ```
- Setting the header response to send in UTF8 with:

  ```
  header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
  ```
- My page does include the meta tag:

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  ```

I'm using NetBeans and it's saving in UTF8.
I can add the characters directly to the HTML and they display correctly.

I hope that all makes sense. Sorry if I've forgotten something important.
Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: Can you isolate whether the issue is related to MySQL at all? When you say " I can add the characters directly to the HTML and they display correctly." do you mean that they display correctly in NetBeans or in a browser? You may need to set the character set for your table's columns, not just the table itself. Can you determine whether the data in your database is not already corrupted?

Comment: Ope. It just started working. I simply had to use the utf8_encode() function. Sorry about that. Should this be deleted?

Comment: Thanks for your willingness!